# How to pass value from VB application to ASP website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

All I could find is "pass values between webpages in asp", but I need to pass a value from a rough vb.net application (running in excel, to be more precise) to the asp.net website.

The reason: the current VB application that is running has an ID. The user clicks a button to launch the browser with a specific website, and according to the ID - the website has specific content. Another user running the VB application, with a different ID, will have different content in the website.

So I need to pass this id (a simple int or whatever) to the ASP so I know what session to launch in the website. How is that achievable (if possible without storing the id in database and then retrieving it)?

P.S. I am testing this by running 2 VS with the website solution open in one and the VB application open in the other VS. I am not sure if that is correct as when all this is deployed, maybe it won't work. And the only solution I can come up with right now is communicating through database.

Comment: Check out query strings, and how to pass query string parameters

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net websites pass data between pages using either the POST or GET method. The GET method involves using the querystring to pass variables. Let's say you wanted to pass the parameter ID to your application, then you would append ID and it's value to the URL:

```
http://www.your-site.com/YourPage.aspx?ID=1234
```

On the YourPage.aspx code behind, you would grab this variable using Request.Querystring like so:

```
Dim intID as Integer = Request.Querystring("ID")
```

So in order to communicate from your VB.Net application to your ASP.Net application, you would simply have the VB.Net app open a link to that page and append the proper ID (or whatever other parameters you need.)

Note: If this is the only security you have to switch between users/permissions/roles/etc. then be aware that any user can change the querystring whenever they want and could technically access other areas of the ASP.Net website.

Comment: Using this method your code will need to validate that the querystring parameters are valid values in your web site.

Comment: Okey, but when I try to open the website with a query string (I start the page like that: `Process.Start("http://localhost:56093/WebSite1?id=" + TextBox1.Text)` then in the address bar the URL is only until the end of `WebSite1`, so there's no query string.

Comment: Try adding the page onto the end of the URL to see if that helps. I'm guessing it's the default page so try something like:     `http://localhost:56093/WebSite1/default.aspx?id=`

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the website, change your ASP page so that it expects a query string parameter containing the ID then have your VB.Net app launch the website using a URL like so:

```
http://your.website.com/somepage.asp?ID=1234
```

In that url, the query string parameter named ID would have your ID that was provided by the VB.Net app.  In your ASP page you can get at this value like so:

```
Dim id = Request.QueryString("ID")
```